# Comparing pairs where sequence does not matter

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

I want to compress data in a table so that there is no redundancy in terms of pair sequence, e.g a,b is same as b,a as pair .

Specifically I want to get from table  : redundant_relations

```
+------+------+------+
| p1   | p2   | score|
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    |  0.8 |
| a    | c    | 0.67 |
| b    | a    |  0.8 |
| c    | a    | 0.67 |
| a    | d    | 0.89 |
| a    | e    | 0.47 |
| d    | a    | 0.89 |
| e    | a    | 0.47 |
+------+------+------+
```

To

```
+------+------+------+
| p1   | p2   | score |
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    |  0.8 |
| a    | c    | 0.67 |
| a    | d    | 0.89 |
| a    | e    | 0.47 |
+------+------+------+
```

Here I just want to select the first relation only and discard the reverse relation as e.g if A and B are friends with score 0.8 I want to keep a single row for their relation as [A,B,0.8] and not two rows i.e [A,B,0.8] and [B,A,0.8], I already have a table which has these relationship existing and I want to remove the later ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you have all pairs, then just do:

```
select rr.*
from redundant_relations rr
where rr.p1 < rr.p2;
```

This gets more complicated if the relationships are not all paired or if the score is not the same.  In that case, I would suggest an index on `(p1, p2, score)` and:

```
select rr.*
from redundant_relations rr
where rr.p1 < rr.p2
union all
select rr.*
from redundant_relations rr
where rr.p1 > rr.p2 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from redundant_relations rr2
                  where rr2.p1 = rr.p2 and rr2.p2 = rr.p1 and rr2.score = rr.score
                 );
```